# Going back from Calendar to my app

Tags: swift, calendar

Im my app, I have this code at a given time:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "calshow://")!)
```

which takes you to the calendar of the device. How could I get back to the scene where that line is executed?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Pressing home (option+shift+h, since the frame is not shown in my iOS Simulator) takes you to home, not the app, as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quote from [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629):

> Unlike other platforms such as Android, iPhone does not create a stack of actions (back stacking on Android). What this means is that if you do decide to launch another application, your application will not resume when the user exits from the application you opened.

If user want to get back to your app, they should press home (option+shift+H) twice, and select the your application from the list.

iOS9 introduced a new "Back-To-App" button at top-left corner, which allow you get back to your application. You should see this button after the calendar is showed from your app.